# Telegram bot on elixir

Tags: elixir, bots, telegram

I'm new on Elixir and I write telegram bot. I use this project as template: https://github.com/lubien/elixir-telegram-bot-boilerplate

It works fine, but I have a couple of questions.

1. How can I split "Commands" if it would be too big? I have an idea to create a new module NewCommands with `use App.Commander` and add it to `handle_cast` in Matcher. Is that a right way?
2. Why does Matcher runs as a GenServer? I don't think it needs any state or smth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please start with reading about the difference between [`use`, `import`, and `require`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) in Elixir.

> We use `import` whenever we want to easily access functions or macros from other modules without using the fully-qualified name.

So no, `use` should not be used here: `import` should. Other way round would be to define commands as macros and `require` them, or write an ad-hoc function generation inside `__using__` macro of `NewCommands` and only then `use` it.

2. I did not dig into the code, but I guess you want `Matcher` to be automatically respawned is something went wrong and it crashed, right? Erlang philosophy is “crash soon,” hence instead of cumbersome error handling we just let the process crash. Aftwerwards, if you still want to match, it should be respawned, to serve further requests.

Also, it is used as a dispatcher before `Commands`.

Comment: I know about import/use/require, but I don't know how to use it in my case. There is a macro module `Commander` and it's being used by `Commands`. I have tried to make a new module (with `use Commander`) and write commands there, and write `import` in Commands but it doesn't work. I

Comment: See how [`Commander#__using__/1`](https://github.com/lubien/elixir-telegram-bot-boilerplate/blob/master/lib/app/commander.ex#L6) is implemented and do the same for your `NewCommands`.